# we are achieving function overloading by writing same method with different type of argument

Tags: python

```
class area:
   def __init__(self):
      self.rad = 0.0
      self.side = 0
      self.length = 0
      self.breadth = 0
      self.ar1 = 0.0
      self.ar2 = 0
      self.ar3 = 0
   def cal(self,r=0.0,s = 0):
      if(r!=None):
         self.rad = r
         self.ar1 = 3.14*self.rad*self.rad
         print(self.ar1)
      elif(s!=None):
         self.side = s
         self.ar2 = self.side*self.side
         print(self.ar2)





obj = area()
obj.cal(7.0)
obj.cal(12)
```

we are achieving function overloading by writing same method with different type of argument but while calling control goes into if part instead of elif part.we want achieve area of circle with if part and area of square using elif but calling for both the argument goes into if part.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by your question, could you clarify it more? Also, you aren't really overloading the function; you overload a function by *defining* two functions with the same name but with different parameters, not *calling* them with different arguments.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by function overloading. It seems like you want to use the *same method* to calculate the area of a square and the area of a circle. This fundamentally doesn't seem designed reasonably. In any event, are you asking how to pass an argument to the `s` keyword parameter?

Comment: you are using default values. s and r will never be none.

Comment: The correct test for `None` (which is an object, not a value) should be `is`, for example `if r is not None:`.  I suspect you are equating `None` to `NULL` in C++, and that is incorrect.  However `bool(None)` is valid and equates to `False`, as does `bool(0)` so you could simplify your conditions (and the parentheses are not needed).

Comment: This is an example where you should **not** use function overloading, in that there is no common code.  `Area` shouldn't be a class, maybe `Shape` should be a parent class and shapes like Rectangle and Circle derived from it, each with their own implementation of Area.

Comment: @cdarke I don't think he's looking for C++ style overloading here, because that's about types, not values. Also, C++ overloading is fine on its own; the hack is how it fits together with template instantiation, template specialization, argument-dependent lookup, access restriction, callable objects, virtual functions, lambdas, and auto/decltype. C++ has a dozen separate systems that have to step on each others' toes in ways that nobody can understand because nobody thought about making them work together until it was way too late. (But I'm sure adding one more, UFCS, will fix it all…)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is those `r!=None` and `s!=None`. At least that's certainly *a* problem that breaks your code; I'm not sure if it's the one you're asking about.

The default values for those parameters are `0.0` and `0`. Neither of which equals `None`.

- If you want to check whether they're nonzero, you could compare `r != 0` and `s != 0`.

  - … or maybe `r != 0.0`
  - … or maybe `not math.isclose(r, 0)`.
- If you want to check whether they're truthy—neither `None` nor zero are truthy, but nonzero numbers are—just check `r` itself.
- If you want to check whether they were left out of the call, you need to instead change the default value in the function definition to `None`.

  - … but then you should check `is not None`, not `!= None`.

---

Meanwhile, what's supposed to happen if you pass values for both of the two? Or neither?

---

Also, if you're expecting people to pass `s` without passing `r`, the only way to do that is as a keyword argument (except by looking at the function definition to see what the default value for `r` is and then passing that explicitly).

So, maybe these should be keyword-only parameters?

---

Putting it all together, here's a guess at what you want:

```
def cal(self, *, r=None, s=None):
    if r is not None:
        raise TypeError('cal() needs either r or s')
    elif r is not None and s is not None:
        raise TypeError('cal() needs only one of r or s')
    elif r is not None:
        self.rad = r
        self.ar1 = 3.14*self.rad*self.rad
        print(self.ar1)
    else:
        self.side = s
        self.ar2 = self.side*self.side
        print(self.ar2)
```

And now:

```
>>> obj = area()
>>> obj.cal(7.0)
TypeError: cal() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
>>> obj.cal()
TypeError: cal() needs either r or s
>>> obj.cal(r=7.0)
153.86
>>> obj.cal(s=12)
144
```

---

But really, there's a much simpler way to do all of this:

```
def circle(self, r):
    # do circle stuff
def square(self, s):
    # do square stuff
```

Easier to write, easier to read—both on the definition side, and on the calling side:

```
>>> obj.circle(7)
153.86
>>> obj.square(12)
144
```